# C++: executing function in main thread from boost thread with io.post and bind command

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, c++11, boost-asio

How should the following command in a boost thread executing doInMainThread() in the main thread look like without c++11 (with the bind function from boost)?

```
//c++11 version, how should I write this without c++11?
io.post([=] { doInMainThread(); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post anything that meets the [Completion Handler type requirements](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/CompletionHandler.html). Instead of a c++11 lambda, you could use `boost::function`

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
io_service.post( boost::bind(&doInMainThread) );
```

Or if you don't want to use `boost::bind`, a function pointer should work fine

```
io_service.post( &doInMainThread );
```

assuming `doInMainThread()` meets the Completion Handler type requirements.